# Android Firestore, Click on Collection to Display Documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wondering is it possible to display the Collections in a List, add a listener to each list item, then when the user clicks a list item (the collection name), that then points to the corresponding documents, and a list can be generated of all the documents.

For Example: The list display all Collections, If the user clicked "Roscommon" the list would then display "Forest Park, Rockfield" and the same again when the user picked one it would display the details.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot achieve this. You cannot display all collections within a document when it comes to Android. You can achieve this only when using Java.

Take a look at **[List subcollections of a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)** and you will see that:

> The `getCollections()` method of the Cloud Firestore server client libraries lists all subcollections of a document reference.
>
> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.